# JSON related error (maybe) on kubectl patch serviceaccount

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm following this [digital ocean tutorial](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/build-deploy-first-image/#step-6-run-your-app-on-a-cluster) and while running the steps, I had ran into an error regarding JSON.

No matter what I pass for `-p`, I always get the given error. Why? I'm on windows? Everything indicates this command is valid.

```
PS C:\Users\me> kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": []}'
Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character 'i' looking for beginning of object key string
```

The above command was suppose to unset the "Image pull secret" so I could re-set it as I'm getting.

```
PS C:\Users\me> kubectl describe serviceaccount default
Name:                default
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  secret/registry-mine-reg (not found)
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>
Events:              <none>
```

Right now, the system can't pull the image although the image appears to be in the registry on DO. This command (the next in the tutorial) was accepted but the image cannot be pulled. (Yes, I replaced  with the correct value.)

`kubectl create deployment my-python-app --image=registry.digitalocean.com/<your-registry-name>/my-python-app`

Comment: As expected, your command works as-is for me on Linux. I suspect (!?) that the issue is with the args|flags on Windows (Powershell). If you append `--v=9` to the command, you'll get the underlying REST call(s) and this may help you debug. Alternatively, my preference for formatting your command would be `kubectl servicesaccount/default --patch='{"imagePullSecrets": []}'`, perhaps that also overcomes the issue on Windows?

Comment: Pods can only reference image pull secrets in their own namespace.Can you check whether the service account and secret are using the same namespace. Also you can achieve adding an image pull secret to the service account by editing the object manually.

`kubectl edit serviceaccount/default` and add lines for imagePullSecrets: and save it.